# How to select only specific keys from postgres json

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, jsonb

I need to extract only specific keys from postgres json, Let us consider the following json

```
{"aaa":1,"bbb":2,"ccc":3,"ddd":7}
```

From the above json i need to select keys 'bbb' and 'ccc', that is

```
{"bbb":2,"ccc":3}
```

I used the following query , but it's deleting the keys

```
SELECT jsonb '{"aaa":1,"bbb":2,"ccc":3,"ddd":7}' - 'ddd}'
```

How can I select only specified keys?

Comment: do you need the result as a json / jsonb or extracted to separate columns?

Comment: i need json /jsonb as result not values

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can explicitely specify keys, like here:

```
t=# with c(j) as (SELECT jsonb '{"aaa":1,"bbb":2,"ccc":3,"ddd":7}' - 'ddd}')
select j,jsonb_build_object('aaa',j->'aaa','bbb',j->'bbb') from c;
                    j                     |  jsonb_build_object
------------------------------------------+----------------------
 {"aaa": 1, "bbb": 2, "ccc": 3, "ddd": 7} | {"aaa": 1, "bbb": 2}
(1 row)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
WITH data AS (
  SELECT jsonb '{"aaa":1,"bbb":2,"ccc":3,"ddd":7}' col
)
SELECT kv.*
FROM data,
LATERAL (
  SELECT jsonb_object(ARRAY_AGG(keyval.key::TEXT), ARRAY_AGG(keyval.value::TEXT)) 
  FROM jsonb_each(col) keyval
  WHERE keyval.key IN ('aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc')) kv
```

The solution works by expanding a `JSONB` (or `JSON`) object, filtering the keys, aggregating the filtered keys & values to create the final `JSONB` (or `JSON`) object.

However, this solution does not preserve nulls, i.e. if `data` had a row where `col` had value `jsonb '{"aaa":1,"bbb":2, "ddd":7}'`, then the above solution would return `jsonb '{"aaa":1,"bbb":2}'`

To preserve nulls, the following form could be used.

```
WITH data AS (
  SELECT jsonb '{"aaa":1,"bbb":2,"ccc":3,"ddd":7}' col
), keys(k) AS (
  VALUES ('aaa'), ('bbb'), ('ccc')
)
SELECT col, jsonb_object(ARRAY_AGG(k), ARRAY_AGG(col->>k))
FROM data, keys 
GROUP BY 1
```